# Determining special intersection points from 3D points defining a surface

Tags: plotting, numerics

I need to calculate a complicated integral. I asked a question:
[Method to compute this integral](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/293309/method-to-make-this-complicated-integration-from-interpolating-function), but my question has been closed.

First of all, I need to get the domain of integration.

I have a solution for that but it is very slow, and this is not compatible with Nbody calculus.

Here is my [data](https://paste.ee/p/4zpaX)

You could have a first look in lin, log log scales.

```
ListPlot3D[datas, ScalingFunctions -> {Identity, "Log", "Log"}, PlotRange -> {10^-5, 200}, Mesh -> False,  AxesLabel -> {"\[Psi]", "R",  Framed["\[Rho][\[Psi],R]", FrameStyle -> None, 
FrameMargins -> 10]}, PlotStyle -> LightGreen]
```

Then I defined two functions to find the points of interest using 3D plot and MeshFunction

```
bornesR[\[Psi]p_?NumericQ, R_?NumericQ] :=  Module[{lsp, points, lesr, lesrho, inters, rmin, rmax, bR, res,  bbasse, bhaute},   lsp = ListPlot3D[datas, MeshFunctions -> {-\[Psi]p + # &}, 
Mesh -> {{0.}}, BoxRatios -> 1, 
ScalingFunctions -> {Identity, "Log", "Log"}]; points = Cases[Normal@lsp, Line[x_, ___] :> x, Infinity][[2]];  lesr = Exp[Transpose[points][[2]]]; rmax = Max[lesr];   rmin = Min[lesr]; lesrho = Exp[Transpose[points][[3]]]; bbasse = rmin; bhaute = rmax; {bbasse, bhaute}  ]


bornes\[Psi][\[Psi]p_?NumericQ, R_?NumericQ] :=  Module[{lsp, points, lesr, lesrho, inters, \[Psi]min, \[Psi]max, bR,    res, bbasse, bhaute, les\[Psi]},  lsp = ListPlot3D[datas, MeshFunctions -> {-Log[R] + #2 &},     Mesh -> {{0.}}, BoxRatios -> 1,    ScalingFunctions -> {Identity, "Log", "Log"}]; points = Cases[Normal@lsp, Line[x_, ___] :> x, Infinity][[2]]; les\[Psi] = Transpose[points][[1]]; \[Psi]max =  Max[les\[Psi]]; \[Psi]min = Min[les\[Psi]]; bbasse = \[Psi]min; bhaute = \[Psi]max; {bbasse, bhaute}]
```

But my method is very slow . Here is an exemple

```
{\[Psi]mi, \[Psi]ma} = bornes\[Psi][-4, 0.01]

{bornesR[\[Psi]mi, 0.01], bornesR[\[Psi]ma, 0.01]} // AbsoluteTiming
```

You could make the corresponding illustration to see the results

```
ListPlot3D[datas,MeshFunctions -> {-\[Psi]ma + # &, -\[Psi]mi + # &, -Log[
   0.01] + #2 &}, Mesh -> {{0.}},MeshStyle -> Directive[Red, Thick], BoxRatios -> 1,ScalingFunctions -> {Identity, "Log", "Log"},  AxesLabel -> {"\[Psi]", "R",  Framed["\[Rho][\[Psi],R]", FrameStyle -> None, FrameMargins -> 10]}]
```

It takes about 1 s to get the 4 points .

[image]

And as I can guess, to calculate the double integral, I will have to make a lot of such findings to complete the integration for one point !!

After that, I will have to apply this method to some thousands points...

My question is the following :

is there another way to get very very quickly the coordinates of the four points ?